# Using Convolution to Isolate bar-code

Tags: matlab, image-processing

My purpose is to take an image with bar-code and other elements (text, numbers etc.)
Like a book cover:
[image: Barcode]
; and to isolate the bar-code from the image. 
The result should be - removing the other elements from the image and keeping 
only the bar-code part.

For this, i was thinking about Convolution as a method for depressing other non vertical lines.

**This is what i have so far:**

```
clc
clear
close all

# %--- Image Read, Double and Gray ------------
Image =imread('barcode.jpg');
Image_Double = im2double(Image);
Image_Gray  = rgb2gray(Image_Double);

# %---- Matrix to be use for Conv -------------
Matrix = [3 0 -3
          3 0 -3 
          3 0 -3];

# %----- Output and Show --------------------- 
Output = conv2(Image_Gray,Matrix); 
imshow (Output,[]);
```

I know there are other methods but i really prefer to stick with convolution for this

---

I just want to clarify that i am new to Image-Processing. Using the code above i got this result:

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2kPs.jpg)

and i need help to continue from here.

Comment: "I would really prefer to use convolution for this", ?!?! `conv2` **IS** convolution

Comment: I don't understand the question. Is `conv2` not giving you the results you want?

Comment: I know :) - as i said "This is what i have so far:" i just mentioned it because i know there are other methods for this, but i prefer using convolution.

Comment: with your convolution matrix, you will tend to find vertical edges. If you can assume that the book cover is always a color other than white, going for the white rectangle may be more successful.

Comment: @Leo If you prefer convolution, you have it there. Whats your question?

Comment: I am sorry guys that i wasn't more clear about my question. I edited the post

Comment: @Leo but that makes sense. You are looking for vertical edges, and you found them. Not only the ones  that belong to the barcode, ofc.

Comment: I know. But as mentioned in the question  -  "The result should be - removing the other elements from the image and keeping only the bar-code part".  If you'll look at the result in the post,  you can see that i am far from "removing the other elements" .  How can i suppress the other elements?

Answer (score 0):

you can use image matching with any bar-code image as template. since all bar-code images are similar(vertical black lines) matching will create more matching points in the bar-code area of the image cover than other areas. Then you can crop the area with high density of matching points. This area will be the bar-code area